# Working within FME and trying to snap newly created line features together within a certain distance of each other

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I have two features, a point feature (addresses) and a line feature (fiber). My end goal is to create a new line feature from the point to the nearest spot on the existing line. I have that process figured out but now I am wanting to fine tune it a bit which is where I am stuck. Currently, it will "snap" the new lines within feet of each other on the existing line and I would like to get it set so that if the new lines snap point is within a certain distance, they snap together at a single spot on the existing span. I have attached a screen capture of my current work flow for reference. I feel like I need another CoordinateExtractor + AnchoredSnapper but my attempts with those aren't returning what I am hoping to do. I have also tried using the plain Snapper but not getting the outcome I wanted.

I am new to FME.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What projection is Addresses and Routes in? in Fibre design normally there is an optical tap/splitter before the fibre drop. https://www.thefoa.org/tech/ref/appln/FTTH-design.html

Comment: Route and addresses are in the same CS and projection. And adding taps will come later in my process, I am just trying to get drops in to show what FME is capable of as opposed to manually drawing ever drop from address to the distribution fiber.

Comment: I think the Snapper is the obvious way to go. Why was the result incorrect? Can the address lines snap to any point on the fibre line? Or can it only be at specific locations?